# Maurice Jondrelle in Skyrim dead- now I need him for the gildergleam quest

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I tried all that but twice Maurice was killed. The first time I reloaded but the second time I was distracted and didn't. So Flash forward to now I went to the cave with the beautiful scenery and the tree. Hacked through the roots despite all the people warning me. and came to the tree and used nettlebane again to get the sap. Then I was attacked by Spriggins and since I'm still developing my magic skills they got me good. I don't see myself being able to beat them and I'd rather not upset everyone in the quest but Maurice is dead :(
I kinda remember where he was killed... is there a solution here? how do I do it?
I'm on an XBox 360 console, not a PC.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz: Not really. That's asking how to keep him alive, and this is asking what to do if he dies.

Answer (score 6):

All you can do is to load an earlier save game. As you know, there is no console available on the 360, so there is not much choice left.

The other option is to level up your magic skills and do the quest the violent way.

Answer (score -1):

Ok so with Maurice, I got him killed twice before trying a safer route. Load an earlier saved game if he is already dead. If you look at the map, the rivers lead straight to the sanctuary. Start sneaking before you get in the water, and then swim there. Come up for air and re-sneak if you have to. Staying sneaked keeps you just out of reach of any riverside enemies you might run in to. You will go over one or two waterfalls but you will avoid enemy camps and keep your companion alive for the mission. If you notice, when you go too far off the path, your companion won't follow you, but instead they will just show up when you're on a reasonable trail again. So he won't swim in the water with you, he will show up when you get to the sanctuary. Of course this is an easy pathway, but it was difficult trying to navigate past bandits and giants with such a delicate and low hp companion. If you just want him to make it there, follow the rivers & swim to the sanctuary.